# Command not found in WSL2 even though it's on the path

Tags: linux, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having an issue with WSL2:

```
$ where b4a
/usr/local/bin/b4a
$ b4a new
/usr/local/bin/b4a: 1: Not: not found
```

Even though `where` finds commands, I can't run them. And it's not a `PATH` issue either:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:[...]
```

And b4a isn't the only command with this problem. What could be the cause? My distribution is Debian 10 and host is Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily a full answer, but hopefully the troubleshooting methods you need to arrive at a solution ...

Note that it doesn't say that the command itself isn't found.  For instance, if you run:

```
# lllllllllll
lllllllllll: command not found
```

That's truly a `command not found`.  This is different.  While I don't (yet) know the exact cause, this seems closer to the issues we might see with improperly quoted paths with spaces in a shell script.

You mention that other commands have this problem -- Is there something in common with the commands that don't work properly?  Is it possible that they are all shell scripts?

Try several things to debug:

- Start WSL without your startup profile.  It's very likely that something (or you) added a line that is causing problems.  From PowerShell or CMD:

  ```
  wsl ~ -e bash --noprofile --norc
  b4a
  ```

  If that works, then there's a problem in one of your startup files that you'll need to debug.  Look for anything modifying environment variables without proper quoting, *especially* the `PATH`.  WSL automatically appends the Windows path to your Linux path to make it easy to run Windows commands, but the fact that almost every Windows path has spaces in it can cause problems for unsuspecting scripters that don't take this corner case into account.

  Having a space in a path is fully allowed in Linux, but some scripts just don't handle it properly.
- If the command that is failing is a shell script, trying starting it with:

  ```
  bash -x /usr/local/bin/b4a
  ```

  Or even start WSL with `wsl ~ -e bash -x` to see *all* trace output from the shell.

  In this case, you'll be looking for some problem in the script right around where it actually fails.
- If all else fails, you can disable WSL's PATH modification via its config file:

  ```
  sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf
  ```

  Add the following:

  ```
  [interop]
  appendWindowsPath = false
  ```

  Then exit Debian, run `wsl --shutdown` and restart Debian.  Try the `b4a` command again.

  If this works, then the problem is almost certainly due to some problem in the `PATH` quoting in these commands.  I don't recommend it as a permanent solution since you will have to type out the full path of Windows applications each time you want to run them.